# Android studio always generate apk more than 80 mb after upgrading react native version

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

Here is my code snippet:

```
 **apply plugin: "com.android.application"
    /**
     * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
     * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
     * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
     * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
     * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
     * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
     * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
     *
     * project.ext.react = [
     *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
     *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
     *
     *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
     *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
     *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
     *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
     *
     *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
     *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
     *
     *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
     *   bundleInDebug: false,
     *
     *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
     *   bundleInRelease: true,
     *
     *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
     *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
     *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
     *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
     *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
     *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
     *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
     *   // bundleInBeta: true,
     *
     *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
     *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
     *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
     *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
     *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
     *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
     *
     *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
     *   root: "../../",
     *
     *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
     *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
     *
     *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
     *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
     *
     *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
     *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
     *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
     *
     *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
     *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
     *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
     *
     *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
     *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
     *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
     *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
     *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
     *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
     *
     *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
     *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
     *
     *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
     *   extraPackagerArgs: []
     * ]
     */
    project.ext.react = [
        enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    ]
    
    apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
    
    /**
     * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
     *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
     *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
     * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
     * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
     * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
     */
    def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
    
    /**
     * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
     */
    def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
    
    /**
     * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
     *
     * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
     * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
     *
     * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
     * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
     * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
     * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
     */
    def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
    
    /**
     * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
     *
     * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
     * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
     * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
     */
    def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.dbazzar.merchant"
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            versionCode 16
            versionName "2.1.1"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        splits {
            abi {
                reset()
                enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
                universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
                include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
            }
        }
        signingConfigs {
    
            release {
                storeFile file('./dbazzarMerchant.keystore')
                keyAlias 'com_dbazzar_merchant'
                storePassword 'h2b2912'
                keyPassword 'h2b2912'
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            debug {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                minifyEnabled false
                debuggable true
            }
            release {
                // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
                // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
                minifyEnabled true
                debuggable false
                zipAlignEnabled true
                shrinkResources true
    
            }
        }
    
        // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
                // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
    //            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
    //            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
    //            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
    //                output.versionCodeOverride =
    //                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
    //            }
    
            }
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0'){
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
        }
        implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
        implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
        implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    
        debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
          exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
        }
    
        debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
            exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
            exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
        }
    
        debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
            exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        }
        implementation files('libs\\paylibrary-release.aar')
    
        if (enableHermes) {
            def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
            debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
            releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
        } else {
            implementation jscFlavor
        }
    }
    
    // Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
    // puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
    task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
        from configurations.compile
        into 'libs'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
    apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
    apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)**
```

Comment: so you want a smaller release apk  size?

Comment: before upgrading react native version the app size was approx 28mb